# Can I name the data when piping readStream to request?

Tags: node.js, stream, request

I am using this code in Nodejs

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'storage server',
  headers: {...},
}

fs.createReadStream('path/to/file').pipe(request(options))
```

but storage server only detects the file if it the field name is 'upload_file'

so can I name the data I send in this case ?

Comment: What you want to name?Is you want to change the filed name or the file you are going to send?

Comment: the field name.

Comment: here you want to read a file and using pipe function you want wite a file in destination folder.Am I right???you want something else?????